# How to create a matrix with huge number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, rstudio, row

I want to create a big dataframe or a matrix.
the dimension of it is: col is 49 and row is 35886996700
When I am trying to create a matrix its giving me an error:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(NA,    # Create empty data frame                                      nrow = (length(genes_union)*length(snp_union)),
                          ncol = col_length))
Error in matrix(NA, nrow = (length(genes_union) * length(snp_union)),  :
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In length(genes_union) * length(snp_union) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
```

I also tried to use big.matrix

```
z <- big.matrix(,nrow=35886996700,ncol=49)

Error in big.matrix(, nrow = 35886996700, ncol = 49) :
  Error: memory could not be allocated for instance of type big.matrix
```

Is there any way to solve this problem so that I can create a matrix with these many rows.

Basically my final output matrix should look like this:
G represent gene and RS represent Ids and T represent different tissues.

```
       T1 T2 T3 ...Tn
G1RS1
G1RS2
G1RSn
G2RS1
G2RS2
G2RSN
GnRSn
```

Comment: The maximum integer size in R is (2^31 - 1). This is also the number of elements in largest vector / matrix you can have. In any case, a matrix of the size you describe would also require several terabytes of memory to store. It wouldn't fit on your hard drive, let alone in memory. Can we ask why you need a matrix that large? Is there a different way to solve the problem you are working on?

Comment: I have to create a matrix for gene-snp information across all the tissues. so my columns will be tissues(which are 49) and then each row will correspond to rsid value present in each gene. since i have 6000 genes and 19000 SNP thats why my matrix is big

Comment: I have edited my question to tell exactly how my final output matrix should look like for a reference. thank you

Comment: @AllanCameron From [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Large-matrices): _Matrices are stored as vectors and so were also limited to 2^31-1 elements. Now longer vectors are allowed on 64-bit platforms, matrices with more elements are supported provided that each of the dimensions is no more than 2^31-1._  I don't know what "longer" means (2^63-1 maybe?). Do you? If the matrix was squarer then (maybe) the number of elements wouldn't be the barrier? As you say though, in any case, this would not fit on most HDs, let alone in RAM.

Comment: @SamR Longer means "of length at most `R_XLEN_T_MAX`", which is defined in the R sources as `2^52` on 64-bit platforms.  Note that `2^53 == 2^.Machine$double.digits` is the maximum integer `n` such that all integers `m` satisfying `-n <= m <= n` can be represented exactly in double precision.

Comment: @MikaelJagan thanks! So if the data in the question was a vector rather than a matrix then the R language itself would not prevent it being created on a 64 bit system...

Comment: @SamR Yeah. Hence OP should consider a 3-dimensional array (gene,SNP,tissue). There is also class `sparseVector` in package `Matrix`, for the sparse case.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to generate a vector of 0's with length 35886996700 * 49:

```
x1 <- 35886996700
x1
[1] 3.5887e+10
x2 <- 49
vec1 <- rep(0, x1 * x2)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 13101.6 Gb
```

I can't see any way to process/manage 13,101GB of data.  A big question is if the matrix is extremely sparse.  Then you may be able to store the data in much more compact sparse format.  If sparse storage is feasible, see the Matrix package in base R: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.5-3

Comment: I tried to use sparse matrix but even then i am getting an error.                                      m <- sparseMatrix(i=5,j=10,dims=c(49,35886996700))
Error in validObject(r) :
  invalid class "ngTMatrix" object: 'Dim' slot contains NA
In addition: Warning message:
In sparseMatrix(i = 5, j = 10, dims = c(49, 35886996700)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Comment: re: `m <- sparseMatrix(i=5,j=10,dims=c(49,35886996700))`  See the syntax for sparseMatrix: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.5-3/topics/sparseMatrix  The basic syntax of the function is passing the i, j index vectors of the non-zero values as well as the indexed values themselves. Your `i=5,j=10` terms indicate a single value at matrix index (5, 10).  However, that one value is not supplied in your function.  Your matrix is so large, I'm guessing it would better to contact someone working in the same domain for tips on ginormous data management.

Comment: thank you. i will contact someone or else break down the matrix into individual ones